# Complexity for converting any propositional formula to CNF format

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, discrete-mathematics

What is the complexity for converting any propositional formula to CNF format? Is it an NP-complete problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard algorithm to transform a general Well-Formed Formula to an **equivalent** CNF has an *exponential run time*, since [in the worst case a n-clauses WFF is equivalento to a 2^n-clauses CNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Conversion_into_CNF).

However, you can transform *in polynomial time* an arbitrary boolean formula into a CNF that is **not stricty equivalent, but satisfable only if the boolean formula is satisfable**. This is the standard reduction used to prove that 3CNF is NP-complete, givent that the more general SAT is NP-complete. See [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1414).